# What is vaamadevya vrata?

Tags: rituals, vrata

What is vamadevya vrata and how is it generally performed?

Which texts deals with its procedures? And what are the fruits of performing it?

Comment: Is this Vata a Vrata performed by the Rishis only? BTW why the downvote?

Comment: @Rickross i am not sure who does and.how is it done